# Tracing a high CPU process

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, monitoring

There have been a few times where a server spikes up to 100% CPU for a moment, during the spike the server becomes basically unusable.

I'm currently looking into solutions to hunt down the process that causes this.

I saw I could use Process Monitor to start recording this information from here on out, but I need something that will run in the background, since the server has a log off policy after X minutes of idle time, and that cannot be altered.

I looked into Performance Monitor as well, but as far as I understood, the processes which PerfMon record depend on the processes that run at the moment of setting up the monitor job. So if the culprit process would execute even as early as one minute after setting up the PerfMon job - PerfMon will not detect it.

We do have a monitoring solution on the server, but unfortunately, since the server's CPU becomes so high, it would not even report it back to the monitoring software and is simply shown as offline in the console.

Answer (score 0):

One software which could help can be found on Github in the
[Clue project](https://github.com/clinthuffman/Clue/).

The setup of Clue installs tasks in the Task Scheduler, so
it survives reboots.

You will find a detailed write-up of setting Clue up and using it
in an article from October 2021 by a Microsoft employee named Becky Burns:
[Automating Data Collection for Memory, CPU, and Disk issues using CLUE](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/automating-data-collection-for-memory-cpu-and-disk-issues-using/ba-p/2843412).